# Error con Subject y Angular RxJS

Tags: angular

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de un crud para publicaciones, funciona, pero estuve investigando de cómo hacer que se haga un 'refresh' al componente, es decir que cuando agrego una publicación inmediatamente se ve reflejado

Mi servicio es este:

```
 URL="http://localhost/api-prueba/";
 private _refresh$ = new Subject<void>();

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 get refresh$(){
    return this._refresh$;
 }

 pushPost(post:any):Observable<Entrada>{
    return this.http.post<Entrada>(`${this.URL}posts/index`,post).pipe(
       tap(
           () => {
             this._refresh$.next();
           }
       )
    );
  }
```

Y mi componente que voy a refrescar es este

```
suscription:Subscription;    
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getPost();
 this.suscription = this.postService.refresh$.subscribe(() => this.getPost());  //jquery
}

ngOnDestroy():void{
 this.suscription.unsubscribe();
}

getPost(){
 this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.entradas = result;
  }
 );
}

publicar(){
 this.postService.pushPost(buffer).subscribe(
    respuesta => {
        console.log(respuesta);
        if(respuesta.message == 'exito'){
          this.added = true;
          this.addPost.reset();
        }else{
          this.addedError = true;
        }
    }
  );
}
```

No se si sirva pero el HTML es este

```
<form (onSubmit)="publicar()">
 .....
</form>
<app-entrada [entradas]="entradas"></app-entrada>
```

app entrada recibe el objeto del servicio y lo imprime!!

La primera vez que lo corres funciona 100% pero si quiero volver a introducir un dato manda error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro saber como resolverlo!

Comment: El error que muestras se produce en la API. Podrías comenzar depurando ahí qué es lo que está mal.

Comment: El API esta bien..!! Porque sin la sentencia del Subject va de maravilla, pero no se actualizan los post hasta que refresca uno la página con F5 o en el botón del navegador, y es que el tema es que cuando inicio el app o cambio y vuelvo a la pantalla, el primer POST si funciona bien, pero ya el segundo marca el error por lo que descarto el back, eso creo yo, y en mi API pido token, pero es que si lo esta mandando, en la solicitud :0

Comment: Depura los datos que se le envían a la api para saber qué falta y poder ubicarlo mejor en el código.